# using .Equals() failing in Predicatebuilder

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, predicatebuilder

Hi I am using Predicate builder to build up my where clause.
 I noticed that it was doing a case sensitive comparison against the entity datasource. Some quick googling implies this is a feature of linqtoentities. so i have had to modify my code  to do

```
whereClause = whereClause.And(x => x.county.Equals(oSearch.County, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ));
```

rather than previously doing

```
whereClause = whereClause.And(x => x.county == oSearch.County);
```

The problem is now it appears to be failing building a whereclause.

incidentally i am using the code below which was working before.

```
var tbl = db.tbl_members.AsExpandable().Where(whereClause.Compile());
```

I have code which does a foreach (var item in Model) this is now failing with a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
if i examine the model using quick view it now shows this

```
tblMembers = {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator<tbl_members>}
```

rather than

```
  tblMembers = {SELECT [Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
[Extent1].[membership_id] AS [membership_id], 
[Extent1].[membership_type] AS [membership_type], 
[Extent1].[institution] AS [institution], 
[Extent1].[full_name] AS [full_name], 
[Extent1].[address1] AS [address1], 
...
```

which it showed previously regardless of any results or not.

Comment: It appears to be? What actually *is* happening?

Comment: well the previous working code throws a null exception and when iexamine the tbl object there is no data returned.

Comment: *Where* does it throw the exception? Please give us all the information we might need... see http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: ok examining the result in debug mode it appears to be returning me a different type of result.Previously regardless of if i had any results or not i could do a foreach (var item in Model) but now it throws a object variable not set to an instance of an object and the object in quickview shows base {System.Linq.Enumerable.Iterator<BASRATMVC4.Models.tbl_basrat_members>} = {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator<BASRATMVC4.Models.tbl_basrat_members>}
rather than
Model = {SELECT 
[Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
[Extent1].[membership_id] AS [membership_id], 
...

Comment: And again, you're not really giving us all the information you have. Please read that link and edit your question.

Comment: sorry jon was trying to insert the comment and CR saved my answer before i had finished.

Comment: It's more useful to edit the question than to put it into comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this:

```
tblMembers = {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator<tbl_members>}
```

it looks like you're inadvertently using LINQ to Objects. Check whether your copy of PredicateBuilder is actually in terms of expression trees (`Expression<Func<T, bool>>`) or delegates (`Func<T, bool>`) - you should be using expression trees.

EDIT: As noted in comments, this is the problem:

```
var tbl = db.tbl_members.AsExpandable().Where(whereClause.Compile());
```

That's compiling the expression tree into a delegate, and then calling `Enumerable.Where`. Without the `Compile()` call:

```
var tbl = db.tbl_members.AsExpandable().Where(whereClause);
```

... we end up calling `Queryable.Where` using the expression tree, which can then be converted into SQL.

Comment: Im using the LinqKit.dll and instantiating my query as            var whereClause = LinqKit.PredicateBuilder.True<tbl_basrat_members>(); sorry im not sure how to check if its using expression trees

Comment: System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<tbl_members,Boolean>> = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<tbl_members,bool>>

Comment: @Tim: Okay, that sounds like it *is* using expression trees... what is `AsExpandable()`?

Comment: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx in this document he seems to say this is necessary for linq to entity.

Comment: @Tim: You've shown what the debugger shows for `tblMembers`, but you haven't told us where that's coming from... could you give more information please?

Comment: tblMembers = db.tbl_members.AsExpandable().Where(whereClause);

just modified my above to remove the compile call. I had put this and the asexpandable in due to the suggestions from the help http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

it appears to work now. Wierd? Thanks for your help Jon!

Comment: @Tim: Ah, I hadn't seen that you were calling `Compile()`. Yes, that makes the whole thing make sense - that was converting from an expression tree to a delegate.

Comment: yes thanks jon still a bit confused as the help says to do this. but it works so i am happy :)

Comment: @Tim: "the help" - which help? There are definitely places where it's good to call `Compile()`, but this isn't one of them...

Comment: just found where i saw it http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx  under "Plugging Expressions into EntitySets / EntityCollections: The Solution"

Comment: @Tim: But that's *within* a where clause in a query expression. It's not really the same thing. It feels like it would probably be worth you studying a bit more about how LINQ works, and the difference between delegates and expression trees. You may find http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/02/20/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-43-out-of-process-queries-with-iqueryable.aspx useful.

Comment: thanks jon for your patience. i will read and inwardly digest. my linq knowledge is pretty basic, much more familiar with raw tsql

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that linq has translation for

```
whereClause = whereClause.And(x =>
x.county.Equals(oSearch.County,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase )
```

in the sql. You can try:

```
whereClause = whereClause.And(x => x.county.ToLower()==oSearch.County.ToLower());
```

Comment: this syntax works if i just use it against the where, its predicatebuilder it appears which doesnt like it.

Comment: incidentally the workaround isnt really a valid solution as it will cause the resulting sql not to use indexes.